# In Angularjs can you sort by selected item using orderByFilter (multiselect listbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to sort a select by 'selected', then alpha on option. If I use jQuery to put the selected items to the top, it looks great until the user deselects one of the options.

Here is the function I created (which didn't work)

```
//User clicked a purpose, move it to the top
self.purposeLbChanged = function() {
    //self.PurposePvmsObj = orderByFilter(self.PurposePvmsObj , 'DROP_DOWN_VALUE', false);  //sort it alpha first... 
    $("#lbPurpose option:selected").prependTo("#lbPurpose"); 
}
```

Is there a way to do this in angular with `orderByFilter`?

Here is the HTML

```
<label>Purpose: </label>
<select name="lbPurpose" id="lbPurpose" ng-model="$ctrl.PurposeSelected" multiple ng-change="$ctrl.purposeLbChanged()">
    <option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.PurposePvmsObj" value="{{option.CD}}">{{option.DROP_DOWN_VALUE}}</option>
</select>
```

Clicked on two items
 [The selected items are at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om3xc.jpg)
.
Deselected an item
[it doesn't go back to original position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ8qE.jpg)

Comment: Could you give a bit more of an explanation? Perhaps showing your HTML would help

Comment: sounds like you need to create 2 arrays. Array 1 has the selected options. Array 2 has the unselected options. Then order by alpha Array 1, 2. Then combine the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a 'position' property to the object to resolve the issue.

```
        //User clicked a purpose, move it to the top
        self.purposeLbChanged = function() {

            //Clear the position
            angular.forEach(self.PurposePvmsObj, function (eachObj){
                eachObj.Position = 0;
            });

             //Sort the list by DROP_DOWN_VALUE
             self.PurposePvmsObj = orderByFilter(self.PurposePvmsObj , 'DROP_DOWN_VALUE', false);

             //Set the selected values first
             var i = 1;
             angular.forEach(self.PurposeSelected, function (eachString){
                angular.forEach(self.PurposePvmsObj, function (eachObj){
                    if(eachObj.CD.trim() == eachString.trim()){
                        eachObj.Position = 1; //if selected it gets a position of 1.
                    }
                })
             })

             //Set the remaining positions
             angular.forEach(self.PurposePvmsObj, function (eachObj){
                if(eachObj.Position == 0){
                    i++;
                    eachObj.Position = i;
                }
             });

             //Sort the list by Postion
             self.PurposePvmsObj = orderByFilter(self.PurposePvmsObj , 'Position', false);
        }
```